# How to select html element located in an iframe on the page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, css-selectors

I am writing webextension to ease account managers login into accounts, when I try to automate login of the user into angularjs app when I try to get login input with js it is not found. The element is represented in browser's inspector panel but is absent in page source.

**UPD:** I found the reason of the issue - this element is located in the iframe on the page and my current issue is how to access iframe's document.
I found that in devtools console there is command 'cd' what does exactly what I need:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById('aid-auth-widget-iFrame');
var ifrContent = ifr.contentWindow;
cd(ifrContent);
document.getElementById('sign-in').value = 'login';
```

But but 'cd' can not be executed from within the script on the page.

Next I did try to access frame's document as:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById('aid-auth-widget-iFrame');
ifr.contentWindow.document;
SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object
```

**Is it possible to execute a js in the iframe existing on the page or select and manipulate an element within this iframe?**

*Deprecated question content:*
I found that angular.element probably may help but it does not find an element also. Probably it's because I tried 'document' what is the same 'document' what I access with vanilla js and where desired element is absent.
Do I need to pass something else to angular.element argument? Tried few selectors like angular.element('div#pageWrapper') as kind of root but getting error(error says that such selector is unsupported)

```
angular.element('div#pageWrapper')
Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/jqLite/nosel
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think angular.element you are using will work for your requirement. Try using angular.element(document).find(#account_name_text_field).

Please refer more info in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Hi, without quotes I am getting  
angular.element(document).find(#account_name_text_field)
SyntaxError: fields are not currently supported

Answer (score 0):

The `find()` method is only limited to lookups by tag name. So you cannot access the element using the method you have shown.

You can instead access the element using the syntax below

```
angular.element($document[0].querySelector('#account_name_text_field'));

// or 

angular.element(document.querySelector('#account_name_text_field'));
```

where `$document` is a jqLite wrapper for the browser's `window.document` object.